# Получение интернета через доступ к чужому роутеру локальной сети

Tags: сеть, роутер, маршрутизация

Есть мой роутер без интернета, подключенный к локальной сети. В этой же локальной сети есть роутер на котором есть интернет. Топологию сети я не знаю, но роутеры хорошо видят друг друга, и у меня есть доступ к админке.

Могу ли я каким-нибудь образом получить доступ к интернету через тот, чужой роутер?

Может статические маршруты как-то прописать?

Comment: То есть тебе нужно одновременно иметь доступ к своему роутеру, не имеющему интернета, и иметь доступ к чужому роутеру, имеющему интернет?

Comment: Нужно чтобы мой роутер принимал интернет от чужого роутера.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого тебе нужен провод LAN (сетевой кабель). Один конец вставь в разъём LAN (жёлтый) роутера, в котором есть интернет, а другой конец провода в разъём Internet (синий), в котором нет интернета. И интернет у тебя подключен.

Comment: Было бы все так просто, не задавал бы вопрос тут. Физически они удалены, просто подключены к одному свичу через WAN.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, роутер, у которого нет интернета, должен ловить сигнал роутера, у которого есть интернет. Функция называется "ретрансляция". Но, к сожалению, она есть не у каждого роутера. В основном у многофункциональных и дорогих.

Не могу сказать на 100%.

Comment: Может настроить роутер, на котором нет интернета в режиме "моста"? При  уже не помню какие параметры для этого необходимы. Но точно знаю что это легко гуглится.